# Finding range of the expression $\sum_{cyc}\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|}$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

Tags: summation, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

I am supposed to find the range of the following. At present I do not know how to get started. Obviously as is the case with numerous symmetrical expressions, one of the extrema occur when all variables are equal, so $3$ would be a value of extrema, but how to prove such an argument rigorously is non-obvious. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|} \text{ for }x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}- \{0\}$$

Comment: Have you tried plugging in various values to guess at the extremes? E.g. is 3 a max or a min? What other values can you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain why you're stuck.)

**Hint:** If $xy \geq 0$, show that $ \frac{ | x+y | } { |x| + |y| } = 1$.
If $ xy < 0$, show that $ 0 \leq \frac{ | x+y | } { |x| + |y| } < 1 $.

Hence, conclude that

$$ 1 \leq \sum \frac{ | x+y | } { |x| + |y| } \leq 3. $$

Comment: So, the minima follows from the case $xy\lt 0, yz\lt 0 \rightarrow xz \gt 0$ at which the expression is $1$. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @ParasKhosla Yes. It would be slightly easier to demonstrate that 1 is the lower bound, and that 1 can be achieved, hence it's the minimum .